# Inserting NULL value into mySQL if the user chose not to upload a file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, upload

Users on my site have the option to upload a few different files.  The code uploads the file and saves a link to that file in a mySQL database.

I am trying to insert a null value into my sql database if the user hasn't chosen a file to upload.

The code below just enters a null value regardless of whether a has selected a file to upload ... please help.  (Location variables are established earlier on in the code and is working properly)

Here's my code:

```
if (is_null($_POST['imgfile'])) {
$imglink = NULL;
} else {
$imglink = mysql_real_escape_string($imglocation);
}
if (is_null($_POST['vidfile'])) {
$vidlink = NULL;
} else {
$vidlink = mysql_real_escape_string($vidlocation);
}

$sql="INSERT INTO db (imgfile, vidfile)
VALUES(
'$imglink',
'$vidlink')";
```

CORRECT CODE:

```
if (empty($_FILES['imgfile']['name'])) {
$imglink = '';
} else {
$imglink = mysql_real_escape_string($imglocation);
}
if (empty($_FILES['vidfile']['name'])) {
$vidlink = '';
} else {
$vidlink = mysql_real_escape_string($vidlocation);
}
```

Comment: Just pass in a null string (i.e. `$vidlink = '';`).

Comment: isn't that the same thing as 'code'$vidlink = NULL;'code' ... ?

Comment: No. PHP null != MySQL null.

Comment: can you post your query then we can help you

Comment: I've trimmed some stuff out to keep it simple, but I added the query to my question.  Does that help?

Comment: @ BenM, I understand that PHP null != MySQL null, but can the null value be set in php before it's put into the database in the sql query, if there wasn't a file selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you sure, that user selected files are available in **$_POST** - not in **$_FILES**?
2. You may just allow NULL and make them default values in your db fields (using **DEFAULT NULL** clause) of table, that store image and video file links - so inserting a new record in a table without these values, automatically will set them to NULL.

Comment: 1. Makes sense, slipped my mind.  I tested it with the change, but it still enters a null value for the link, even if the user selects a file to upload.

Comment: 2. The code renames the uploaded files for security and upon renaming, it inserts a name for a file without an extension, if the user doesn't select a file to upload.  So the problem is that if someone clicks on the link to that extension-less file, the user ends up on a 404 redirect page.  I want it to insert a null value if the user doesn't select a file, but post the link to it if they do.  Does that make sense? @viktor-livakivskyi

Comment: NUMBER 1 tipped me off to the solution. The input for uploaded files posts to php in an array and so my original code was treating the array as one inputted value.  I needed to identify a value within the array and run the if/then against that for it to work properly.  Thanks, @viktor-livakivskyi.  Since I am new to Stack Overflow and can't post an answer to my own question, I'll edit my original question with the correct code below it all.

Comment: @AaronB. you're welcome! Sometimes solution lies in a different scope :)